# Command \textcap unavailable in encoding T1

Tags: pdftex

I get for commands `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, `\listoflistings`, and `\chapter` the same error:

```
Command \textcap unavailable in encoding T1.
```

Even cloning a fresh latex template results in this error, for example this on from GitHub: https://github.com/timkpaine/oreilly-latex-template

To be clear, the PDF *does* generate, but all those things are missing in the document (titles, table of contents, etc.)

Here's the preamble for that example, just for reference (sorry that it's kind of long):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,
                             twoside,
                             BCOR1.0cm,
                             DIV11,
                             parskip=full,
                             11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[standardsections]{scrhack}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{color}

%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFixedFont{\numcap}{T1}{phv}{bx}{n}{3cm}
\DeclareFixedFont{\textcap}{T1}{phv}{bx}{n}{1.5cm}
\DeclareFixedFont{\textaut}{T1}{phv}{bx}{n}{0.8cm} 

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{gray}\textcap}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{white}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{white}}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\small\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\sffamily\small}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    draw=black!20, thin,
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered},
  peu/.style={
    rectangle,
    fill opacity=1,
    %rounded corners, 
    fill=white,
    top color=white,
    draw=black!20, thin,
    %text width=10em, 
    %minimum height=3em, 
    text centered},
  line/.style={draw, thin, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=10em, 
    minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\headheight}{25pt}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setheadwidth{textwithmarginpar}
\setheadsepline{.4pt}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{lightgray}}

\lefoot{\color{black!40}{\hrulefill}}
\cefoot{\parbox[c][.5in][c]{1cm}{\fcolorbox{black!40}{white}{\thepage}}}
\refoot{}

\lofoot{\color{black!40}{\hrulefill}}
\cofoot[{\color{black!40}{---}} {\thepage} {\color{black!40}{---}}]{\parbox[c][.5in][c]{1cm}{\fcolorbox{black!40}{white}{\thepage}}}
\rofoot[]{}

\usepackage[pdftex,             
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Llibre amb estil},
    pdfauthor={Joan Queralt Gil},
    pdfsubject={tema},
    pdfkeywords={Keyword1, Keyword 2},
    bookmarks, bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

\tolerance=4000
\emergencystretch=20pt

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\usekomafont{sectioning} \usekomafont{chapter}\filleft}
    {\numcap\textcolor[named]{gray}\thechapter}
    {1em}
    {}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section}
     \tikz[overlay]  \fill[color=black,rounded corners=.2ex] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth-2cm,1em);}
    { \thesection}
    {1em}
    {}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
    {\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{subsection}
       \tikz[overlay] \fill[color=black!60] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth-2cm,1em);}
    { \thesubsection}
    {1em}
    {}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[steps]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,labelindent=0.5cm,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[steps,1]{label*=\arabic*.}
\setlist[steps,2]{label*=\arabic*.}
\setlist[steps,3]{label*=\arabic*.}
\setlist[steps,4]{label*=\arabic*.}

\newlist{points}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[points]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,labelindent=0.5cm,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[points,1]{label=\tiny\ding{110}}
\setlist[points,2]{label=\tiny\ding{108}}
\setlist[points,3]{label=\tiny\ding{72}}
\setlist[points,4]{label=\tiny\ding{117}}

\newlist{objectives}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[objectives]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,labelindent=0.5cm,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[objectives,1]{label=\tiny$\blacktriangleright$}

\newlist{attention}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[attention]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,labelindent=0.5cm,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[attention,1]{label=\ding{224}}


\newlist{arrows}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[arrows]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,labelindent=0.5cm,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[arrows,1]{label=\tiny\ding{252}}
\setlist[arrows,2]{label=\tiny\ding{212}}
\setlist[arrows,3]{label=\tiny\ding{232}}
\setlist[arrows,4]{label=\tiny\ding{217}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\newcommand\novaimatge{\includegraphics[width=14pt]{write}}
\renewcommand\logowidth{14pt}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\let\shline\hline
\def\hline{\noalign{\vskip3pt}\shline\noalign{\vskip4pt}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% First Page
\title{\textcap{Latex Template}}
\author{
    \textaut{Joan Queralt Gil}\\http://catalatex.blogspot.com/
}
\date{\today}

\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
```

Here's what `latex --version` outputs:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Homebrew)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

I'm on Mac, using VS Code with LaTex Workshop. I feel like I'm missing something small that could be causing this error. It's been a while since I've worked with LaTeX, so bear with me if it's obvious!

Comment: You've chosen a bad name for the font. Change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `hyperref` will define `\textcap` at begin document, thus overriding your font definition.

If you *really* want to mix Helvetica with Computer Modern (or other font), then use the proper way (***not*** fixed font). But a fix for your issue is to replace `\textcap` with something else, such as `\chapterfont`.

By the way, `titlesec` is not compatible with `scrbook`. And don't redefine `\hline`; rather use `booktabs` rules. Also remove the `pdftex` option.

Comment: Perfect, renaming `\textcap` to something else fixed the compile error for me! I'm going through your other recommendations, with the `pdftex` option, do you mean to remove that from the `\documentclass`?

Comment: Without `titlesec`, how can format my titles? It seems to work if I leave it in...

Looks like that template I found is either long deprecated or the authors themselves also didn't know all these rules.

Comment: @fullStackChris I'd use `book` with `fancyhdr`.